# Selenium - Handle random webpage display and continue test scripts

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, bigcommerce

We have developed more than 50 test cases using Selenium + TestNG and Java for a Big Commerce web application. While executing the test cases application is randomly displaying a "Enter preview code" webpage where-in we have to enter the application preview code and click on submit to proceed further. Due to this random webpage display test cases are failing since Selenium couldn't identify the desired web element.

We want to handle the "Enter preview code" webpage by entering the preview code and click on submit button whenever it displays during test execution and continue with the test scripts without failing the test case. Kindly help!!

**Edit**: Please refer https://www.screencast.com/t/JBJFtNuvowk to view the "Enter preview code" webpage

**Note:** One way to handle the "Enter preview code" webpage is to append query string parameter **guestTkn="xyz"** to all the redirected URLs e.g,,https://xxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/?guestTkn=9143adsf, but we don't know how to append guestTkn param to all the URL's.

Comment: Is it when your are at the page that you can just driver.get(driver.current_url + yourstring) to redirect or am I am mistaken.

Comment: As you mentioned we can append guestTkn param in driver.get  ,but that will be used only while invoking the application, but say after invocation if any hyperlink/ button is clicked page will be redirected without the guestTkn param in the current URL, due to this “Enter preview code” web page will display.

Comment: Couldn't you recheck if that page comes up during actions then.

Answer (score 1):

Need more in details at perticular what kind of actions or activity "Enter preview code" is displayed as alert. If it is displayed as javascript alert,You can locate element then put a condition like `if(element.isDisplayed == true){execute code}`

Comment: Thanks Hardik, it is not an alert it is a webpage where we'll have to enter the preview code and click on submit. Please refer the updated link to view the "Enter preview code" page